# Is it possible to load the menus (vue-router) from the application server on vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

I would like to be able to manage the active menu items and roles from the server side (application server) cms. So that when I disable a menu item it doesn't show up on the SPA at the same time.

Is there a way to render the vue-router items (menus) based to the application server (actually to the database)?

PS: The SPA will be (webpack) pre-compiled.

Comment: Where is the Problem ? A router-link is basic component. You can use v-for on it and loop through whatever "navigation data" you have.

Comment: @FrankProvost yes thats right. actually there isn't a problem. I am just looking for convenient a way to import the "navigation data" from the application data. I could not find any examples where the "navigation data" was not hard coded in route but instead imported from the application server. I guess I simply get the nav data over axios and use it in the router. just like that.

Comment: So you actually want the routes to be blocked then right? You will probably need to manually check this in a before navigation method then. For the moment I can only imagine a "hack" solution where you put the navigation data to window directly (window.navData = ...) and use the routes before navigation method to check if it exists there

Comment: Yepp @FrankProvost, that looks the way to go right now. I will give it a try ;)